# getting format not a string literal even if I add %s

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have looked around for answer on various forums, tried various things and still getting this error:

`warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]`

The compiler point to the line in the function that has the error, here's how it looks:

```
int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char *searchstring) {
    int note_length;
    char byte=0, note_buffer[100];

    note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);
    if(note_length == -1)  // if end of file reached
        return 0;           //   return 0

    read(fd, note_buffer, note_length); // read note data
    note_buffer[note_length] = 0;       // terminate the string

    if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring)) // if searchstring found
        scanf("%s", note_buffer) // Got this line from an answer in the forums
        printf(note_buffer);  // compiler points here
    return 1;
}
```

If you want the full code i can post it here, but its kind of long :/ don't know if that will be ok.

Comment: It's nice that the compiler points at the line with the error, care to share where that is? Also you're missing curly brackets around the printf/scanf, and the "%s" as mentioned below

Comment: LOL was too focused on something else and forgot to add the important part. I'll edit it now

Comment: the indentation does the thing for me so no need to add curly brackets

Comment: This is not Python. Indentation means nothing to a C compiler. Your `printf` is **outside** the `if(search_note...`. Add brackets!

Comment: You must have miscopied the code into the question because the compiler should be complaining about the absence of a semicolon (or possibly a comma) after the `scanf()` and before the `printf()`.

Comment: I fixed the problem (misplaced files), and the code works regardless if add the curly brackets or indent the lines. After all i am following the steps in the book, and that's how its done by the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its giving warning for :

`printf(note_buffer);`

As you are getting string being formed at runtime and trying to print it.

Use :

`printf("%s",note_buffer);`

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko then may be same problem at other places too, read the line numbers carefully